# Unique Identifier in multiple schemas

Tags: postgresql, schema, unique, primary-key

As the title suggests I want to have a unique ID as a primary key but over multiple schemas. I know about UUID but it's just too costly.

Is there any way to work this around a serial?

Comment: you can add column with schema id and create PK on two columns. this way id will be serial, but keypair will be always unique between schemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a global sequence and use that in your table instead of the automatic sequence that a `serial` column creates.

```
create schema global;
create schema s1;
create schema s2;

create sequence global.unique_id;

create table s1.t1
(
   id integer default nextval('global.unique_id') primary key
);

create table s2.t1
(
   id integer default nextval('global.unique_id') primary key
);
```

The difference to a `serial` column is, that the sequence `unique_id` doesn't "know" it's used by the `id` columns. A "serial sequence" is automatically dropped if the corresponding column (or table) is dropped which is not what you want with a global sequence.

There is one drawback however: you can't make sure that duplicate values across those two table are inserted manually. If you want to make sure the sequence is **always** used to insert values, you can create a trigger that always fetches a value from the sequence.